# HP ZBook laptop doesn't turn on after shutdown

Tags: boot, laptop, power

I have an HP ZBook Fury 17 G7 Mobile Workstation. Today I shut it down, but when I later pressed the power button to turn it on nothing happened - no lights, nothing.

How do I fix this, if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching on various sites, the solution turned out to be to unplug the power supply and then press the power button for 2 minutes in order to do a "reset" (not sure of what - the BIOS?). After that the laptop could turn on and everything was fine.

It has to be no less than two minutes, I had tried pressing the power button for a long time but I didn't know it had to be that long!

Comment: Wow.  I have this same laptop.  This is good to know.  BTW, this laptop is FAST!

Comment: This will probably be to totally discharge any residual charge left in the components. I have a similar problem currently where just my power button doesn't work. Currently working around the problem by enabling the "Power on when opening lid" option in the BIOS.